# Typo3 Directmail Can not create Newsletter

Tags: typo3

I have typo3 system with directmail installd

One in godaddy delux linux hosting In this system I canot create newsletter from internel or externel page 
"The plain text content could not be fetched.
The HTML content could not be fetched."
This meesgae shown

and one in pleask linux hosting plane same typo3 installation But it work normally

Quick mail is working on both system

my htacces and php5.ini  in godaddy show below

RewriteEngine On
AuthType none
Satisfy Any
RewriteRule ^typo3$ - [L]
RewriteRule ^typo3/.*$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule .* index.php

and php5.ini

register_globals = off
allow_url_fopen = on

expose_php = Off
max_execution_time = 180
max_input_time = 180
memory_limit = 256M
variables_order = "EGPCS"
extension_dir = ./
upload_tmp_dir = /tmp
precision = 12
post_max_size = 16M
upload_max_filesize = 16M

SMTP = relay-hosting.xxxxxserver.net
url_rewriter.tags = "a=href,area=href,frame=src,input=src,form=,fieldset="

[Zend]
zend_extension=/usr/local/zo/ZendExtensionManager.so
zend_extension=/usr/local/zo/4_3/ZendOptimizer.so

Thank you

Mujeeb

Comment: check boundaries and format config in your dmail typoscript. Are you using tv?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are missing these in your template's "**Include static**" section.

```
Direct Mail Content Boundaries
Direct Mail Plaintext
```

Answer (score 0):

Besides the response above I also had to make some changes to the host linux file so CURL could fetch the html:

http://devbackyard.blogspot.com/2012/10/direct-mail-typo3-content-could-not-be.html